# How to implement Chromedriver in Hound with Elixir

Tags: elixir, selenium-chromedriver, hound

I'm trying to start an elixir project with hound for browser automation. I can get it working with firefox just not chrome. My chromedriver is set in my environment variables on my system and this is my config.exs file `use Mix.Config
        config :hound, driver: "chrome_driver", port: 4560`

I'm running a selenium server on port 4560. I made sure that hound is listed in my dependencies as well. Please let me know what I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I needed to npm install -g chromedriver and run the command in the command line then run mix test on my test with the right config settings and it now works.